# .NET NumericUpDown with Decimals=AsNeeded

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have situation where is needed to make cyclic calculation where any of 3 NumericUpDown control changes his value. All those controls have seted property 'DecimalPlaces' to 2. But there are some numbers where I need more decimals if I want to get proper result in cyclic calculation.

So now I would need one of NumericUpDown controlls (less important) to have changable number of decimals say 'AsNeeded'.

For example if number is 1.2345 control should have setted 4 decimals, in case of 0.10 they should have 1 decimal places to show a number.
Of course I would like that this property changes automatically regard of number which is needed to be shown.

Any advice to get NumericUpDown control to work that way?

Comment: It is pretty unclear how you intend to read the user's mind, the kind of feature required to guess how many digits he wants to enter.  NUD is just not the appropriate choice, use a TextBox instead.

Comment: You could handle it's [ValueChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Hans, it is NOT about user's choice but about number of decimals which number have. If user want to input here then NUD don't limit it in any number of decimals again. After his input I validate it and there I can set DecimalPlaces according his input. Or I think wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the number of decimal places shown by the NumericUpDown control as needed:

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    Dim ud = DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown)
    Dim val = Math.Abs(ud.Value)
    Dim frac = (val - Math.Truncate(val)).ToString().TrimEnd({"0"c})
    ud.DecimalPlaces = Math.Max(frac.Length - If(val < 0, 3, 2), 0)
End Sub
```

We are only interested in the fractional part of the number. We don't want any trailing zeros.

When converted to a string, the fraction will have two leading characters (zero and a decimal separator), unless it is negative, in which case there are three leading characters (a minus sign, zero, and a decimal separator).

If you are unhappy with going via a string to get the number of decimal places, then you could do it like this:

```
Private Function Frac(d As Decimal) As Decimal
    d = Math.Abs(d)
    Return d - Math.Truncate(d)
End Function

Private Function NumberOfDecimals(x As Decimal) As Integer
    x = Math.Abs(x)
    Dim nPlaces = 0

    While Frac(x) > 0
        x = x * 10D
        nPlaces += 1
    End While

    Return nPlaces

End Function

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    Dim ud = DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown)
    ud.DecimalPlaces = NumberOfDecimals(ud.Value)
End Sub
```

which should work for the range of values you are like to use a NumericUpDown control for. I would not want to use that method with a Double or Single as a lot of decimals are not represented exactly in floating point format.

Note that technically 0.1 is not the same as 0.10 - the former could represent a number in the range [0.05, 0.15) and the latter [0.95, 1.05).

Comment: Thanx Andrew. I though to avoid string operations but OK, this is OK for beginning...

Comment: @user1697111 As this is for a UI control, I would not worry about using string operations.

Comment: @user1697111 I added a method which avoids string operations.

Comment: OK, I have to compare those solutions now and pick which one would look/work better. My NUD's are subclased so I can use this code in subclass and turning it on/off with one new boolean property say 'DecimalPlacesAsNeeded'. Thanx.